# parse (input) to JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

Hello not overly familiar with JavaScript quite new to it actually so i pulled bits from other projects and now struggling to wrap things up.

This is for a small RGB lighting project. The json payload message is transported via MQTT and the initial input is a string value as follows "rrr,ggg,bbb".

what i have come up with so far is as follows

```
(function(i) {

  var rgb = i.split(",");
  var color = {"r":rgb[0],"g":rgb[1],"b":rgb[2]}
  return JSON.stringify({color});

})(input)
```

Desired result needs to be `{"color":{"r":232,"g":200,"b":55}}`

the JS gets stored as a .js file and referenced when transformation is needed

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting an error?  What is not working?  What kind of help are you looking for?

Comment: Executing the JS-transformation failed: An error occurred while loading JavaScript. <eval>:5:30 Expected : but found }
  return JSON.stringify({color});
                              ^ in <eval> at line number 5 at column number 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are creating your inner object correctly, but the value you are stringifying is just the inner object wrapped in braces, you need to change your stringify line to:

```
 return JSON.stringify({"color": color});
```

The way you currently have it written, would come out as

```
{{"r":232,"g":200,"b":55}}
```

Comment: nailed it that was exactly what i was getting. Made the suggested adjustments, got it working.  Thank you for the help.